# QTcreator: problem to set background color in checkbox's

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serv2 = new serveur(this);
    timer = new QTimer(this);

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this,&Dialog::fonctionHeure);
    timer->start(1000);

    connect(this, &Dialog::envoyer_message_connexion2,serv2, &serveur::Connexion);
    connect(serv2, &serveur::reponseServeur,this, &Dialog::onReponseServeur);

    ui->checkbox->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator{background-color:red;} QCheckBox::checked{color:green;}");    
}
```

Hello everyone,

I want to change the background of my checkbox's, I tried this :

`QCheckBox::indicator{background-color:red;}`

but this completely ruins the tickbox: the depth-effect is gone, and also no checkmark appears anymore when the checkbox is selected

How can I change the background color without resetting all other stylings ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a background of QCheckBox's indicator in this way, because it is drawn with images.

Take a look at [customizing QCheckBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox)

You should create your own image set for the states your checkbox  will have and use them in stylesheet.